# Calling an animation function to animate button causes unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, animation, react-native

I have a text field, and when the length is greater than 1, a button appears from the bottom. if it is zero, the button disappears. It uses componentWillReceiveProps to check if the button "isVisible" from props passed down from parent.

This is the animation function:

```
  animateButton(toValue, speed) {
    if (this.state.isMidAnimation) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ isMidAnimation: true }, () => {
      Animated.timing(this.state.animatedBottomOffset, {
        toValue,
        duration: speed,
        delay: 0,
      }).start(() => {
        this.setState({ isMidAnimation: false });
      });
    });
  }
```

It is triggered within componentWillReceiveProps, and it's animation, depending on visible or not, goes up by the height of the button, or down by the height:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.isVisible !== this.props.isVisible) {
      const currentOffset = this.state.animatedBottomOffset._value;
      const offset = nextProps.isVisible ? this.props.height : - this.props.height;
      this.animateButton(offset + currentOffset, BUTTON_TOGGLING_SPEED);
    }
  }
```

This functions as expected if I let the animation complete, and looks great. The problem arises is when I quickly go between textInput field length 0 and 1, back and forth, and the button, rather than stay in either the "on" or "off" position, starts having it's final position higher and higher, or lower and lower, until it is off the screen.

I suspect it has something to do with `this.state.animatedBottomOffset._value`, but that's something I need to set as it's the height of the keyboard when the component mounts, and the state check of whether it is `isMidAnimation` does not seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't return here:

```
if (this.state.isMidAnimation) {
  return;
}
```

You should keep the reference of the ongoing animation. Stop the ongoing animation, and start a new one in this if statement.

Comment: Ah, how do I get the reference, or stop the animation?

Comment: Also, why does returning not solve the problem? Shouldn't it let the animation complete?

Comment: for instance:

const buttonAnimation = Animated. timing(......).start();
buttonAnimation.stop()

Comment: Not sure why this is the correct approach, shouldn't this allow the animation to finish, and then animate backup (or down)? I'm unsure if the need for setting the state to isMidAnimation is necessary. I also tried setting the animation to an instance variable, but no luck in that function.

Comment: this.state.animatedBottomOffset._value will no longer be synced with the value of your textInput if you return there.

Whether to let the animation complete is more about UI/UX. You could also queue the animations up. As long as you feel it's smooth.

Comment: Any chance you can provide an example of either queuing them up, or "stopping" with the example code I have above? I guess my suspicion was correct.